# Conditional formatting logic for does not contain

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Name, Job title and Team.   I am wanting 'Name' to show a color when   both 'Job title' AND 'Team' does not contain 'IT' in it. 
I currently have value does not contain 'IT' but i am unsure how to add logic for 2 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Job title in column B and Team in column C and starting your CFR Applies to: in row 2 try,

```
=iserror(match("*it*", $b2:$c2, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("IT",CONCATENATE(B2,C2)),0)
```

Comment: ahh why didn't i think of that......... some times the answers are the simplest ones..... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Late in the day. Here's one more formula for CF:

`=COUNTIF(B2:C2,"*IT*")=0`